# How big are regular (hyperbolic) polygons?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

**Given a hyperbolic surface of constant curvature $K=-1/a^2$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, is there a known formula for the length of the edges of a  regular polygon?**

I know that the Gauss–Bonnet theorem tells us that the area of an $n$-gon is given by:
$$A=(n-2)\pi-\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = n(\pi-\alpha) - 2\pi$$
But i'm not sure how one would go about calculating the edge length without explicitly specifying the surface. Is an explicit formula even possible?

Comment: Does it matter that the surface is embedded in $\mathbb R^3$? Your questions seem so be only intrinsic properties of the surface.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - No, but since I'm new to the topic, I wasn't 100% that the length was an intrinsic property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $r$ is the distance one of the vertices of the polygon to its center. Draw the perpendicular bisector of the edge; by symmetry it will pass through the center of the polygon too. This creates a right triangle where

- The central angle is $\pi/n$.
- The hypotenuse is $r$.
- The opposite leg is half the edge length.

Applying the appropriate [rule for a right hyperbolic triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_triangle#Trigonometry_of_right_triangles) we get
$$ \sin \frac{\pi}{n} = \frac{\sinh(x/2a)}{\sinh(r/a)} $$
where $x$ is your sought edge length.

This is easily solved to get
$$ x = 2a \sinh^{-1} ( \sin(\pi/n) \sinh(r/a) ) $$

---

If instead of the radius you know the interior angle $\theta$ at each corner of the polygon, you would use a different rule and get
$$ \cosh(x/2a) = \frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sin(\theta/2)} $$
giving
$$ x = 2a \cosh^{-1}\left( \frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sin(\theta/2)} \right) $$

Comment: Just realized I could use the law of hyperbolic cosines, but I get a slightly different result, which I'll post below.

Comment: Henning - Do you know why we get different results?

Comment: @nbubis: Our results are not really different -- you can convert mine into yours by the double-angle formula for hyperbolic consines: $\cosh(2x)=2\cosh^2(x)-1$, and then $\cos^2\frac\pi n = \frac12+\frac12\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Law of cosines to the rescue:

If we know that the angle at each vertex is $\theta$, and the edge length to be found is $x$, then:

$$\cos(2\pi/n)=-\cos^2(\theta/2)+\sin^2(\theta/2)\cosh(x/a)$$
Or:
$$x = a\cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(2\pi/n)+\cos^2(\theta/2)}{\sin^2(\theta/2)}\right)$$